# sqlite return same value on left join

Tags: sql, sqlite

in below my sqlite command i want to get count of `barcoeds` when that's equals with `sessions.id`

```
select sessions.id, sessions.session_name, sessions.session_type,sessions.date_time, count(barcodes.id) as barcode_count 
from sessions left join barcodes
on sessions.id = barcodes.session_id
group by barcodes.id
order by sessions.id desc
```

this command works, but that return more data with same value, for example if data is one, that return more than `3`, but really i have one row

```
0 = {_List} size = 5
 0 = 11
 1 = "111"
 2 = 2
 3 = "1398/05/14 ساعت:  08:43"
 4 = 1
1 = {_List} size = 5
 0 = 11
 1 = "111"
 2 = 2
 3 = "1398/05/14 ساعت:  08:43"
 4 = 1
2 = {_List} size = 5
 0 = 11
 1 = "111"
 2 = 2
 3 = "1398/05/14 ساعت:  08:43"
 4 = 1
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample  .. you actual result and your expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge post updated, thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged sqlite *and* MySQL? (About the only databases this query won't just produce an error on...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want one row per session.  So, your query is aggregating by the wrong column:

```
select s.id, s.session_name, s.session_type,
       s.date_time, count(b.id) as barcode_count 
from sessions s left join
     barcodes b
     on s.id = b.session_id
group by s.id
---------^ sessions not barcode
order by s.id desc;
```

You might find this also easy to do with a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*,
       (select count(*) from barcodes b where b.session_id = s.id)
from sessions s;
```

The use of table aliases in these queries makes them easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

First count the `id`s for each `session_id` in table `barcodes` and then join to `sessions`:

```
select 
  s.id, s.session_name, s.session_type, s.date_time, 
  coalesce(b.barcode_count, 0) barcode_count 
from sessions s left join (
  select session_id, count(id) barcode_count
  from barcodes
  group by session_id 
) b on s.id = b.session_id
order by s.id desc
```

I guess `id` is unique in the table `barcodes` so there is no need for `count(distinct id)`.